# How can I have the user be asked to add text over the desired image?

Tags: python

I need a bit of help completing this.. I was attempting to do this for fun and thought it would be easy! Now it's something I want to continue doing...

I am trying to get the user running the program to receive a prompt asking them to add text on the top of the image. *Such as raw_imput()?* ( like a meme generator ).

This is the code I have so far. I am currently using the application Canopy.

Thanks!

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageDraw
import os

filename = os.getcwd() + "\meme.jpg"

pic = Image.open(filename)

pic.show()
drawing_layer = ImageDraw.Draw(pic)
drawing_layer.text("Hello")
drawing_layer.show()

new_pic = ImageOps.posterize(pic,8)
new_pic.show
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get input from the user, use the following code:

`text = input("Please enter the text to overlay: ")`

then use `text` as the text to draw over the image: `drawing_layer.text(text)`